# How to play both Live & DVR streaming

Tags: media-player, jwplayer, wowza

I am using wowza for video streaming. I have created a live application with DVR functionality.  It's working fine with the Wowza Adobe HDS player.  I was using JW Player, which was working only for live streaming.  Please help regarding players which support both live and dvr streaming.

Comment: What version of JW Player?  If it's version 7, their [documentation](http://support.jwplayer.com/customer/portal/articles/1430265-dvr-live-streaming) states that you need the Premium edition.

Comment: This is correct. It used to apply for only Enterprise and Ads in JW6, but now it is Premium for JW7!